# Validation on a dynamically set MultipleChoiceField, where the field is initially empty?

Tags: python, ajax, django, validation

I've got a view with a few different forms in it. The first form has a search field which populates a multiple choice field, and when the user types in their query in the search field, an AJAX call is sent to bring all records which match the query. The user then selects the choices from the first multiple choice field and clicks "Add" to move them to a different Multi Select Box

This works fine, but when the form submits, I receive an error that reads 
"Select a valid choice.1 is not one of the available choices.". 
I have tried setting the choices after receiving arguments in the form init, but that doesn't seem to work.

My Form:

```
class SiteCoordinatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    selected_studies = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required = False)
    site = forms.ChoiceField(required = False)    
    studies = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required = False)
    study_search = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SiteCoordinatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        if args:
            study_list = []
            query_dict = args[0]
            self.fields['selected_studies'].choices = [(int(x), x) for x in   query_dict.getlist('selected_studies')]

        self.fields['site'].choices = [(x.pk, "%s (%s)" % (x.primary_name, x.primary_number)) for x in Site.objects.all().order_by('primary_name')]

    class Meta:
        model = SiteCoordinator
        exclude = ('studies', 'site', 'selected_studies')
```

My AJAX function which populates the box:

```
def search_studies(request):
    return_data = {}
    studies = []
    make_query = lambda terms, fieldname: reduce(lambda x, y: x & Q(**{fieldname + '__icontains': y}), terms, Q())
    if 'search_text' in request.POST:
        terms = request.POST['search_text'].split()
        for rec in Study.objects.filter(make_query(terms, 'name')):
            studies.append({
                'study': {'id': rec.id, 'name': rec.name, 'number': rec.id}
            })

    response = {'status': 'success', 'count': len(studies), 'studies': studies}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response), mimetype="application/json")
```

The function to populate the MultiSelectBox:

```
function show_results(data, status_code, request){
    recs = data.studies;
    var select_box = document.getElementById('id_studies');
    select_box.options.length = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < recs.length; index ++){
        select_box.options[index] = new Option(recs[index].study.name,
                        recs[index].study.id,
                        false, false);
    }
}
```

Then the JQuery to move the choices:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#id_studies option:selected').remove().appendTo('#id_selected_studies');
    return false;

});

$('#remove').click(function() {  
    $('#id_selected_studies option:selected').remove().appendTo('#id_studies');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: For now I've solved this by having a hidden multi select field with all of the choices, then having the choices that have been filtered moved to that multi select. This is a little work-around for now, but I'd like to eventually figure it out.

Comment: i have the same problem, but the work-around with a hidden multi select is not possible for me bacause it will have 6000+ options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear that we don't want validations of `MultipleChoiceField` but do want `MultipleSelectWidget` so solution is simply to change field to

```
studies = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
```

and do your own validations in

```
def clean_studies(self):
    ...
```

Comment: This is perfect for me, except, I get back a unicode string of a list of unicode strings, like:  u"[u'Canada', u'Mexico']" .   How can I avoid this or parse it without a complete hack?

Comment: @JohnLehmann, some months later  I've posted a new answer that refers to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the solution proposed by @AnuragUniyal and that also answers @JohnLehmann's comment:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    new_tags = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        for tag in eval(self.cleaned_data['new_tags']):
            models.Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
        return instance
```

Basically we transform the string of a list of unicode strings back into a Python list applying `eval()` on it.